# In a Jupyter Notebook server's Terminal, how do you activate a Kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebook servers have an integrated way to open a Terminal:

[image: Menu in Jupyter Notebook server to open a Terminal]

but then in the Terminal, how do I activate a Python Kernel as it opens with the system's default Python activated?

Answer (score 0):

The Terminal accepts the Unix command:

```bash
$ source activate your_Python_Kernel_name
```

which then allows you to do things like install new packages into the Python Kernel:

```bash
(your_Python_Kernel_name) $ pip install pandas
```